# Чи зберігається подвоєння приголосних у словах іншомовного походження, які позначають сорти рослин?

Tags: велика-мала-літера, подвоєння

Запитання в заголовку виникло через необхідність записати в кулінарному рецепті назву одного з сортів гарбуза мускатного: «баттернат» з подвоєнням чи «батернат» без подвоєння (англ. «butternut squash»). Якщо застосовувати правила, наведені нижче, то припускаю, що має бути «батернат» у кулінарному рецепті як загальна назва складника та «Баттернат» у статті з ботаніки як власна назва сорту.

> 1. У загальних назвах іншомовного походження букви на позначення приголосних звичайно не подвоюємо: …
> 2. Подвоєння букв на позначення приголосних переважно зберігаємо у власних  назвах: … У  загальних назвах,  які  утворені  від власних  назв  без додавання  афіксів,  букви  на  позначення  приголосних  не  подвоюємо: …

> 2. У неспеціальних текстах назви сортів рослин беремо в лапки і пишемо з малої букви  (зокрема й власні назви): *пшени́ця «золотоколо́са», груша «парижа́нка», троя́нда «гло́рія-дей», мали́на «гера́кл»*.
> 3. У спеціальній літературі в назвах сортів рослин  перше слово (і всі власні назви) пишемо з великої букви: *сморо́дина Софії́вська, огіро́к Корольо́к, тюльпа́н Ре́мбрандта, карто́пля Серпа́нок, сли́ва Зарі́чна ра́ння*.

Answer (score -2):

**Butternut українською**

> [§ 128. Неподвоєні й подвоєні букви на позначення приголосних](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/%202019.pdf)
>
> **3. Подвоєння букв на позначення приголосних переважно зберігаємо у власних назвах та в загальних назвах, які від них утворені за
> допомогою афіксів і т. ін.**: *Андо́рра* (*андоррець*), *Голла́ндія*
> (*голла́ндський*).
>
> ```
> У загальних назвах, які утворені від власних назв без додавання
> афіксів, букви на позначення приголосних не подвоюємо: *ват* (пор.
> *Ватт*), *гаус* (пор. *Гаусс*), *бекере́ль* (пор. *Беккере́ль*).
> ```

### Гарбуз «Баттернат»

Це овоч видовженої грушоподібної форми з блідою затверділою шкіркою та насичено-помаранчевою м’якоттю. Він солодкий на смак і має їстівне насіння з тонким горіховим ароматом.

[Butternut squash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cucurbita_moschata#/media/File:Cucurbita_moschata_Butternut_2012_G2.jpg) - це штучно створена рослина, отримана в результаті селекційного схрещення гарбуза Хаббарда з [Gooseneck squash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crookneck_squash)(Гусешиїм кабачком). З погляду ботаніки **[Cucurbita moschata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cucurbita_moschata)** - це не гарбуз (до яких відносять лише C.Pepo і C.Maxima), а [зимовий кабачок](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winter_squash), що насправді є фруктом і, навіть, ягодою. Він виник у Волтемі, штат Массачусетс, де був розроблений на експериментальній станції Робертом Е. Янгом в 1944 році.

Відпочатку «Баттернат» не мав власної назви, а на місцевому риночку люди просто питали «ослячі гарбузи». Дороті Леггетт стверджує, що зимовий кабачок **Waltham Butternut** був розроблений в 1940-х роках її покійним чоловіком Чарльзом Леггеттом зі Стоу, штат Массачусетс, а потім представлений ним дослідникам на польовій станції Волтем (Уолтем). Вона також запевняє, що назва **[Butternut](https://www.farmersweekly.co.za/crops/vegetables/the-strange-history-of-the-butternut/)** походить від **“smooth as butter, sweet as nut”** (**«ніжний, як масло, солодкий, як горіх»**).

Відомий на весь світ **Waltham Butternut** став після перемоги на [All-America Selections (AAS)](https://all-americaselections.org/product/squash-waltham-butternut/), де він був представлений вченими з Массачусетського університету у 1970 році. Від того часу будь-які гарбузи, що за формою нагадують неочищений арахіс і мають геном Waltham Butternut, називають **батернатами**.  Сьогодні їх існує величезна сила [різновидів](https://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/PlantFinder/PlantFinderDetails.aspx?taxonid=279569&isprofile=1&basic=cucurbita) ([«Баттербейбі»](https://www.johnnyseeds.com/vegetables/squash/winter-squash/butterbaby-organic-f1-butternut-squash-seed-4197G.html?cgid=winter-squash#prefn1=prod_feature_cat_ref&prefv1=201&start=1), [«Баттерскоч»](https://www.johnnyseeds.com/vegetables/squash/winter-squash/butterscotch-pmr-organic-f1-butternut-squash-seed-3983G.html), [«Метро»](https://www.johnnyseeds.com/vegetables/squash/winter-squash/butterscotch-pmr-organic-f1-butternut-squash-seed-3983G.html), [батернат «Авалон»](https://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/PlantFinder/FullImageDisplay.aspx?documentid=21288), [батернат «Зеніт»](https://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/PlantFinder/FullImageDisplay.aspx?documentid=21289), та   [ін.](https://www.johnnyseeds.com/vegetables/squash/winter-squash/?prefn1=prod_feature_cat_ref&prefv1=201)).
[image: Фото гарбуза «Баттернат» з магазину «АТБ»]

> [**Гарбуз мускатний**](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B7_%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9) – плоди за довжиною поділяють на дуже великі (понад 60 см), великі (50-60 см), середні (35-50 см) та дрібні (менше
> 35 см). Форма плода довбнеподібна, циліндрична, з перехваченою
> (вузькою) серединою і розширеною верхньою і нижньою частиною, рідше
> сплюснута, округла й овальна. М’якуш жовтий, жовтогарячий,
> жовто-червоний, ніжний, щільний, із мускатним запахом. Цей вид не має
> кормових і овочевих сортів. [Держпродспоживслужба України](https://dpss-ks.gov.ua/novini/nishevi-kulturi-garbuz)

У [Державному реєстрі сортів рослин, придатних для поширення в Україні](https://sops.gov.ua/reestr-sortiv-roslin)  (стор. 360-464), станом на 6.01.2022, в наявності є 12 сортів гарбуза мускатного (Butternut, [Butternut squash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butternut_squash), Cheese Pumpkin) і один гібридний сорт.
[image]

Comment: Привіт. Я не знаю, чому люди ставлять мінуси, але припускаю, — бо їм важко зрозуміти структуру цієї відповіді: що є основною тезою, а що є аргументами (на підтримку основної тези). Шкода, що відповідь не оцінили. Мені здається, сприйняття відповіді читачами можна змінити невеличким переформулюванням.

Comment: Sasha, дякую за вашу підримку. Більше місяця по крупинкам збирав матеріали, щоб надати розгорнуту відповідь на це запитання. Досі вона ще не завершена. Слід додати як Butternut squash трансформувався в мускатний гарбуз і потрапив до словника Бельгауза, а звідти до радянських енциклопедій і до української класифікації, що їх наслідує радянську. Після того окремим коментарем запитаю на вашу допомогу, Sasha, щоб структурувати інфу і відповідь стала корисною для відвідувачів Stackexchange. Добре?)

Comment: Звісно, я лише за! (Просто мені було шкода, що недоліки у формі можуть зашкодити зрозуміти глибину суті.)